# How to output array of shape [ 1, 28, 28,1] from a tflite model as image in android

Tags: java, android, numpy, tensorflow

I have a saved **tflite model** whose input and output details are as follows:

1. **Input** :[{'name': 'dense_4_input', 'index': 0, 'shape': array([  1, 100], dtype=int32), 'shape_signature': array([  1, 100], dtype=int32), 'dtype': , 'quantization': (0.0, 0), 'quantization_parameters': {'scales': array([], dtype=float32), 'zero_points': array([], dtype=int32), 'quantized_dimension': 0}, 'sparsity_parameters': {}}]
2. **Output** : [{'name': 'Identity', 'index': 22, 'shape': array([ 1, 28, 28,  1], dtype=int32), 'shape_signature': array([ 1, 28, 28,  1], dtype=int32), 'dtype': , 'quantization': (0.0, 0), 'quantization_parameters': {'scales': array([], dtype=float32), 'zero_points': array([], dtype=int32), 'quantized_dimension': 0}, 'sparsity_parameters': {}}]

How do I display the output as image on an android app using Java with Tensorflow interpreter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import android.content.res.AssetManager
import android.graphics.Bitmap
import android.util.Log
import org.tensorflow.lite.Interpreter
import org.tensorflow.lite.Tensor
import java.io.FileInputStream
import java.lang.StringBuilder
import java.nio.ByteBuffer
import java.nio.ByteOrder
import java.nio.channels.FileChannel

class ImgPredictor(val assetManager: AssetManager, modelFilename: String) {
    private var tflite: Interpreter

    private var input: ByteBuffer
    private var output: ByteBuffer

    init {
        val tfliteOptions = Interpreter.Options()

        val fd = assetManager.openFd(modelFilename)
        val inputStream = FileInputStream(fd.fileDescriptor)
        val fileChannel: FileChannel = inputStream.channel
        val startOffset: Long = fd.startOffset
        val declaredLength: Long = fd.declaredLength
        val mbb = fileChannel.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, startOffset, declaredLength)
        tflite = Interpreter(mbb, tfliteOptions)
        Log.i("ImgPredictor", "interpreter: ${tflite.detail()}")
        input = ByteBuffer.allocate(100 * Int.SIZE_BYTES)
        input.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder())

        output = ByteBuffer.allocate(1 * 28 * 28 * 1 * Int.SIZE_BYTES)
        output.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder())
    }

    fun predict(data: IntArray): Bitmap {
        val startTs = System.currentTimeMillis();

        input.clear()
        output.clear()

        input.rewind()
        for (i in 0 until 100) {
            input.putInt(data[i])
        }
        tflite.run(input, output)
        val bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(28, 28, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        // vector is your int[] of ARGB
        bitmap.copyPixelsFromBuffer(output)
        return bitmap
    }
}

fun Tensor.detail(): String {
    return "[shape: ${this.shape().toList()} dataType: ${this.dataType()}, bytes: ${this.numBytes()}]"
}

fun Interpreter.detail(): String {
    val sb = StringBuilder("interpreter: \n")
    sb.append("input: { \n")
    for (i in 0 until this.inputTensorCount) {
        sb.append("    ").append(this.getInputTensor(i).detail()).append("\n")
    }
    sb.append("}, \n")

    sb.append("output: { \n")
    for (i in 0 until this.outputTensorCount) {
        sb.append("    ").append(this.getOutputTensor(i).detail()).append("\n")
    }
    sb.append("}")
    return sb.toString()
}
```

You can see the official tutorial here for more details:
[Example of object-detection interpreter](https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/blob/f61466134db544776a1819cbe7af8673c7626216/lite/examples/object_detection/android/app/src/main/java/org/tensorflow/lite/examples/detection/tflite/TFLiteObjectDetectionAPIModel.java#L152).
But here are some points you should notice:
1. Keep the `implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite:x.x.x'` same version with your PC as possible for some ops may not work in lower version.
2. Using some detail func to print the interpreter input/output.
3. Check the input output data buffer order endian.

Comment: The above code is throwing Runtime exception: " Buffer not large enough for pixels"

Comment: Try to keep your code run smoothly pass-through the code . Make sure you output int32 is an RGBA format data, you can debug it.